# Summing up products from java loop

Tags: java

I am having problems with summing up the products produced from my java loop.

```
public class ArtificialNeuron {

    public ArtificialNeuron(double[] weightings) {
        weights = weightings;
        inputs = new double[6];
        inputs[0] = 1;
    }

    public void setInput(int index, double newValue) {
        inputs[index] =  newValue;
    }

    public int activate(double threshold) {
        double x = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<inputs.length;i++)
            x = inputs[i]*weights[i];
        double sum = x+x+x+x+x+x;
        if(sum >= threshold) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

I ran several Junit test and it always seem to fail on the if else statement. I believe it probably my summation method, but I don't know how I would sum up the products.

Comment: First please format your code per Java standards so that we can more easily read it and understand it. If we can easily understand it, we're better equipped to help and answer the question.

Comment: Not really directly to your question, but `x+x+x+x+x+x` is `6 * x;`, to your question - the loop sets one `x`; so you have one product with `x = inputs[i]*weights[i];` (the last one).

Comment: In the words of Charles Babbage, "I am not able rightly to apprehend the confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question."

Comment: Along the lines of @ElliottFrisch, you'll need to do something like this: `x += (6*x);`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I think you wanted to *add* all of the products together. Instead, you are multiplying the last product by 6 (effectively). It's unclear why you have the temporary `x`, you can add each product to a default `sum` of `0`. Also, I think a test for `sum < threshold` is a little easier to read (likewise, *always* use braces with your loops - it's easier to read and reason about). Like,

```
public int activate(double threshold) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        sum += inputs[i] * weights[i]; // sum = sum + (inputs[i] * weights[i])
    }
    if (sum < threshold) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```